# Grails 3/4/5 Spring Security Plugin login by email

Tags: grails, spring-security

We upgraded a Grails application from version 3 to 4. With all dependencies, including Spring Security on 4.0.4. Previously, users had logged in with their name and password. We now wanted to change that to the email/password combination.

I set the value in the application.groovy: `grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'`. Then I tried that in the application.yml. However, I cannot login with the email. It still works with the username. I'm now using Grails 5 and Spring 5. The application runs without errors, but the login doesn't work. Does anyone have any advice? Thank you.

After another debug session: The problem seems to be that the loadUserByUsername() method is called twice in the UserDetailService. The first time it finds the user with the email, but the second time it runs through the query with the username and therefore finds nothing. Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

For us we just added a email validation to username field, and added another name field of type String as the display name for user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, I guess now, the rememberMe value. Don't know exactly how I can solve this now.

Answer (score 0):

We also changed to email from username.

We have UserDetailsService.groovy under src/main/groovy/packagename.

Here is the code:

```
class UserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {
    
    static final List NO_ROLES = [new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly=true, noRollbackFor=[IllegalArgumentException, UsernameNotFoundException])
    public MyUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        

            User user = User.findByEmail(username)

            if (!user) throw new NoStackUsernameNotFoundException()

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {
                //new GrantedAuthorityImpl (it.authority)
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority (it.authority)
            }
            
            return new MyUserDetails (user.email, user.password, user.enabled,
                !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id,
                user.firstName, user.lastName)
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String, boolean)
     */
    @Override
    public MyUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        return loadUserByUsername (username)
    }

}
```